# How to setText on last button click in a series

Tags: android, button, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, counter

I have a simple counter app which displays the button count in a `TextView`. This is also sent in an `ArrayList` of an `ArrayAdapter` to log the time the button was pressed. At the moment, every time the button is pressed it logs it. Although, i want it to only log the last time it is pressed in a series of pressed.

for example: if the button is pressed 3 times in the space of 3 second i want the log to just show 1 line displaying '3' instead of 3 lines displaying '1'. Then if it is pressed another 5 times in 3 seconds it shows '3' on one line and '5' on the next. At the moment it would display 8 lines all with '1' on it.

ill need some sort of onLastClickListener or something along those lines but i can't work it out...

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: You just have to create a simple time check variable

Answer (score 0):

There's no on"last"clickListener...  You have to teach an onClickListener how to understand what a last click is.  Example to get you started:

```
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            long lastClickTime = 0;
            int countClicks = 0;


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                long newClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if((newClickTime - lastClickTime) <= 3000){
                    countClicks++;
                }else{
                    lastClickTime = newClickTime;
                    countClicks = 1;
                }

                //Do Something with countClicks;
            }
        };
```

Comment: how do i implement the countClicks though? i want it to only work on the last number before it is reset back to 1? i dont want it to update on every click. I think re on the right track though.

Comment: post a runnable to a handler with a 3 second delay, put the variables in the activity context-scope, have the runnable call a function to see if an intervening click has been made, and if it hasn't, write your result to your textView.

Comment: sorry, im very new to programming with java. how would i go about doing that?

Comment: I have made a runnable with a 3 second delay but i can't figoure out how to restart the count if the delay is interupted...

Comment: Have the runnable repost itself to the handler with a delay.  It should finally complete (not repost) when it complete's its task.  Be careful not to repost infinitely.

Comment: could you post an example please? i am having no luck with this. i understand what you are saying i just can't work out how to implement it.